# Underfull hbox(10000) at \begin{document}

Tags: warnings

I am new to Latex and I have these strange warnings which say :

```
/File.tex:79:Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
/File.tex:79:Underfull \hbox (badness 1337) in paragraph
/File.tex:79:Underfull \hbox (badness 1881) in paragraph
/File.tex:79:Underfull \hbox (badness 1803) in paragraph
```

The strange thing is that the line referred to `79` is the `begin{document}` line.

It also does it for other lines which happen to be the begginings of new paragraphs.

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

This is the tex code up to the `begin{document}` line :

```
%% -*- TeX -*- -*- FR -*-

%Avant propos : ces exemples de fichiers ont été mis à jour grâce à
%l'aide précieuse de Gilbert Ritschard. Pour toute question ou
%remarque n'hésitez pas à nous contacter : venturin@univ-tours.fr ou
%gilbert.ritschard@themes.unige.ch
%Version 3 2008-05-21
%Version 3.1 2012-11-26 Bruno Pinaud <bruno.pinaud@labri.fr>

\documentclass[a4paper,french]{rnti}
%\documentclass[a4paper,french,submission]{rnti}  %% pour soumission à EGC

%\documentclass[a4paper,french,noresume]{rnti} %% Pour papier de 2 pages

%%% Avec l'option "showlayout" vous obtenez les deux pages
%%% de contrôle des paramètres de mise en page.

%\documentclass[a4paper,footer,french,showlayout]{rnti}

%packages nécessaires pour écrire des articles en français en utilisant les accents non latex.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

%pour bien présenter les URL et autres adresses emails
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}

\pretolerance=10000

% Titre court pour entête
\titrecourt{XEWGraph : Visualisation et Analyse des Hypergraphes}

% Noms auteurs pour entête :
%    Si un seul auteur, mettre : Initiale. NomPremierAuteur
%    Si deux auteurs, mettre : Initiale1. NomPremierAuteur et Initiale1. NomDeuxiemeAuteur
%    Si plus de deux auteurs, mettre comme ci-dessous
%
\nomcourt{Z. BOULOUARD, A. EL HADDADI et L. KOUTTI}

\titre{XEWGraph : Outil de Visualisation et Analyse des Hypergraphes pour un Système d'Intelligence Economique }

\auteur{Zakaria BOULOUARD\affil{1},
        Anass EL HADDADI\affil{2}\\
         Lahcen KOUTTI\affil{3}}

\affiliation{
    \affil{1}Faculté des Sciences Agadir\\
          zboulouard@gmail.com\\
    %
    \affil{2}ENSA Al Hoceima\\
          anass.elhaddadi@gmail.com\\
    %
    \affil{3}Faculté des Sciences Agadir\\
          lkoutti@yahoo.fr
 }

\resume{%
L'Intelligence Economique (Competitive Intelligence en anglais) est un ensemble coordonné de recherches, d'extractions et de traitements 
d'informations utiles pour les décideurs afin de leur faciliter le processus de prise de décision. Le Système d'Intelligence Economique 
Xplor EveryWhere (XEW) permet à ses utilisateurs de rechercher, afficher, valider et rediffuser l'information utile. Sur ce papier, nous 
allons présenter l'outil Xplor EveryWhere puis nous allons nous concentrer sur son nouveau module XEWGraph dédié à l'analyse des données 
massives et la visualisation des hypergraphes.
%
}

\summary{%
Competitive Intelligence est a set of coordinated researches, extractions and treatments of information that stakeholders find useful for
them in order to ease the process of decision making. The Competitive Intelligence System Xplor EveryWhere (XEW) helps its users search,
visualize, validate and share useful data. In this paper, we will intorduce Xplor EveryWhere and we will spot the light on its newest 
feature called XEWGraph, which is dedicated to the analysis of massive data and visualization of hypergraphs.
%
} 


\begin{document}
```

Comment: Something is hooking onto `\begin{document}`.  You should post a full MWE that includes *just* enough to replicate the issue if you want us to be able to help -- this isn't really enough information to go on.  (And welcome to TeX.SX!!)

Comment: are you using `\\ ` at the end of the paragraphs (if so, don't:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know that mistake could cause underfull boxes -- isn't it essentially `\hfill\newline`?

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : No I have never used `\\ ` , all I do is pressing the `enter` button twice in order to leave a blank space.

Comment: I tried https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/RNTI.cls but just get `! Undefined control sequence. l.15 \titrecourt` on your example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you please explain what it means?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried deleting `\titrecourt` from my tex code but it still gives me the same warnings

Comment: Please edit your example so that it generates the warnings you give, and confirm if the above is the correct `.cls` file, or give a link to a different one as `RTNI` (or `rtni` ?) is not in the normal tex distributions/

Comment: by "my tex code" do your mean your original document, or the document posted above. It is only the latter we can see.

Comment: `\begin{document}` is on line 32 of the posted code so presumably the warnings are from a different document? Please post the warnings you get from the document as posted here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK I will update eventhough the other lines are just text and comments

Comment: "the other lines are just text" That was the text with the paragraphs that generated the warnings.

Comment: Oh I see! OK I will post it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please check the update!

Answer (score 2):

You can get a bit more information about the boxes by adding

```
\showboxdepth100
\showboxbreadth100
```

to the top of the file, then look in the log.

Note the lines are all reported at `\begin{document}` as this class incorporates the command usually known as `\maketitle` into the `\begin{document}` setup. The commands for author, address etc do not typeset anything they just save the data, so the warnings are reported when the text is set.

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 81--81

\hbox(0.0+0.0)x375.57628
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

That was is an infinitely bad box with a blank line that has no text or stretchy glue, that is trying to be full width. (as stray `\\` is common cause of this)

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1275) in paragraph at lines 81--81
\T1/ptm/m/n/10 un ensemble coordonnÃ[] de recherches, d'extractions et de trait
ements
```

That's not so bad, tex just had to stretch the white space a bit more than it would like to set that paragraph

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1852) in paragraph at lines 81--81
\T1/ptm/m/n/10 de prise de dÃ[]cision. Le SystÃ^^Dme d'Intelligence Economique 
Xplor
```

same

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 81--81
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x375.57628
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

another infinitely bad line that looks like white space

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1275) in paragraph at lines 81--81
\T1/ptm/m/n/10 un ensemble coordonnÃ[] de recherches, d'extractions et de trait
ements
```

again tex had to stretch white space to fit this line

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1852) in paragraph at lines 81--81
\T1/ptm/m/n/10 de prise de dÃ[]cision. Le SystÃ^^Dme d'Intelligence Economique 
Xplor
```

The main reason that TeX is having problems setting this text is

\pretolerance=10000

which really has no good effects, deleting that line makes them go (apart from one 10000, which is probably a spurious `\\`)
I should note I had problems saving the posted text in utf8 for some reason.

Comment: I just got you, you were checking the wrong `cls` file, the right one is `rnti.cls` and it is in this [folder](http://www.editions-rnti.fr/files/RNTI-X-Y2.1.zip)

Comment: @user1885868 odd there should be different classes with same name:-) OK will edit in a bit.

Comment: @user1885868 updated with correct class

Comment: In fact, in all the sentances you have mentioned, I was pressing the button `enter` and starting a new line because I didn't want to scroll left and right every time, and that didn't affect the resulting text anyway. Would that be the reason for this mess?

Comment: @user1885868 a newline is the same as a space in tex, you can always reformat the source code in any convenient way, it doesn't affect the output. two newlines make a paragraph

Comment: OK, so how can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: @user1885868 oh! you have `\pretolerance=10000` That's the main problem, delete that

Comment: I added it because I had several `Overfull \hbox` warnings and those are not tolerated by the committee to whom I plan on sending my article. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @user1885868 there's various ways to avoid overfull boxes, it depends why they are overfull but telling text to allow infinitely bad paragraphs before trying hyphenation is unlikely to ever make a good result